# Replace particular html tags using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to replace every `<li>` tag with `#`  & every `</li>` with `<br />`

I think I need a global replace function for that rather than a simple `string.replace()` so...

```
var s=obj1.innerHTML;

 s = s.replace(/<li>/g,&quot;# &quot;);
 s = s.replace(/</li>/g,&quot;<br/>&quot;);
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Any mistake ?

**EDIT:** I am going to use the code in blogger & that is why it needs to be parsed.So that's why you see `&quot;` instead of `"`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Do this way:-

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/uGY8A/)**

```
var s="<div>hello world <br/><li>First LI</li><li>Second LI</li></div>";   
s = s.replace(/<li>/g, "#");  
s = s.replace(/<\/li>/g,"<br/>"); 
alert(s);
```

Comment: Hi @siva charan please tell me how can I delete the tag and whatever it contains in b/w. 
I am using something like this replace(/<title[^>]*>[\T\t]*?<\/title>/g,'');
But not working.
Much thanks

Comment: so you can just use your html tag inside the first replace arg. You only need to escape tag-end-slashes, not angle brackets. Like `.replace(/<p><br><\/p>/g, "<p></p>")`

Answer (score 7):

Sorry but if the `li` tag has some attribute (like style) you will have text that you don't want. For me the simplest way is using regular expressions like this:

```
var regex = /(<li[^>]+>|<li>|<\/li>)/g;
s = s.replace(regex , ' ');
```

In the case you want to strip all the `<tags> </tags>` (not only li tags) you should do something like this:

```
var regex = /(<[^>]+>|<[^>]>|<\/[^>]>)/g;
s =s.replace(regex , ' ');
```

Comment: you can use this one 
    /(<li [^>]+>|<li>|<\/li>)/g  (the same but with an space) and it will go fine for you.

Comment: Yes, I had modified it like this `/(<li >|<li [^>]+>|<li>|<\/li>)/g` already, with the first `<li >` ensuring tags with only a single additional space are replaced as well.

Answer (score 6):

```
obj1.innerHTML = obj1.innerHTML.replace(/<li>/g, '#').replace(/<\/li>/g, '<br>');
```

You just have to escape the `/` in `/li` otherwise it will be taken as a regex delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://streamed.in/static/js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var s = $('#obj1').html();
        s = s.replace(/<li>/g,'#');
        s = s.replace(/<\/li>/g,'<br/>');
        $('#obj1').html(s);
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body id="obj1">
    <li>omg 1</li>
    <li>omg 2</li>
    <li>omg 3</li>
    <li>omg 4</li>
</body>
</html>
```

or you can try and replace your second replace line with:

```
s.replace(/<\/li>/g,'<br/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late to the party, but all the previous answers are using RegExp(s) and *you don't need Regular expressions* to replace an HTML tag with another one:

**Simple Example - Replace h1 with h2**

```
const oldElement = document.querySelector('h1');

// Create a new element
const newElement = document.createElement('h2');
newElement.textContent = oldElement.textContent; // Copy content from old element to new one

// Replace old element with the new one
oldElement.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, oldElement);
```

**Answer to the question**

```js
function replaceLiTags() {
  const HTMLElementsLi = document.querySelectorAll('li');

  [...HTMLElementsLi].forEach(el => {
    el.parentNode.append("#" + el.textContent);
    el.parentNode.append(document.createElement('br'))
    el.remove();
  });
  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 2</li>
  <li>test 3</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="replaceLiTags()">replace tags</button>
```

NOTE: you should always have `LI` as children of `UL`.
So what you trying to achieve is not syntactically correct since according to *W3C* lists are made up of sequences of list items defined by the `LI` element.

Answer (score -4):

If you can use jQuery, this would help you:

`$("li").after("#<br/>").remove();`